# Как перевести телефоны вида +79031559499 к виду +7 (930) 383-88-33?

Tags: javascript

Как перевести телефоны вида +79033838833 к виду  +7 (930) 383-88-33?

Comment: а если Белоруссия например, там что-то типа +385 999...

Comment: https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Comment: [mdn replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: так вроде же регулярка, которую вам предложили в другом таком же вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/750697/191482...... зачем алгоритм? или вы хотите какой-то бОльший код писать?

Comment: Вопрос задан ответ получен, зачем плодить вопросы, если что то не устроило, можно вопрос дополнить конкретикой...

Answer (score 7):

Очень приблизительно через замену регуляркой:

```js
var tel = '+79031559499';
var tel = tel.replace(/\+7(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '+7 ($1) $2-$3-$4');
console.log(tel);
```

P.S. И не ясно, что это у вас в вопросе один номер телефона преобразился в совершенно другой.

Comment: поправил. это для примера. именно нужно к маске такой преобразовать

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery(function($){$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");});
```

Используй скрипт маски для номера - [ссылка](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Comment: А jQuery вообще-то не просили.