# Перевод номера в другой формат PHP

Tags: php

Как перевести номер вида +79000066808 в вид 8 900 006-68-08?

Comment: Аналог для js https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/750697/186083

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так

```
$result = preg_replace("/\+7(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})/", "8 $1 $2-$3-$4",  "+79000066808");
```